# What does char.MaxValue has to do with string index search?

Tags: c#, .net, string, search

I was looking at our codebase and I found

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetViewBetween<T>(this ImmutableSortedSet<T> set, T min, T max)
{
    var index = set.IndexOf(min);

    if (index < 0)
    {
            // No exact match found, but "larger" items are available.

        index = ~index;
    }

    while (index < set.Count)
    {
         var item = set[index++];

         if (set.KeyComparer.Compare(item, min) >= 0 && set.KeyComparer.Compare(item, max) <= 0)
         {
             yield return item;
         }
         else
         {
             break;
         }
    }
}
```

Which really searches for objects between `min` and `max`. What intrigues me however is the string case and the call to this method.

Suppose we have following structure of the set (already sorted) `[ "esent", "event", "eventamazing", "ewent" ]` and we query the set with term `"ev"`. I've been told that this does sort of index search and in this particular case `GetViewBetween` returns `[ "event", "eventamazing" ]`which is exactly how I want it to be, but then the call to this method is the following:

```
set.GetViewBetween(term, term + char.MaxValue).ToImmutableList();
```

I've always thought that strings are compared by length or char by char depending on the comparer (`KeyComparer` in my case is `OrdinalIgnoreCaseComparer`), but I cant get my head around how concatenating `char.MaxValue` works in this case?

Comment: Imagine the only characters are a-z then basically that's just appending z to the end of the term so everything from "ev" to "evz".

Comment: Your 'OrdinalIgnoreCaseComparer' works just like a normal dictionary, not just looking at length: a<event<events<evz<z

Comment: Ordinal will compare the characters at the same location until it finds a difference or it runs out of characters to compare in which case the shorter one is considered to come first.

Comment: ow, so everything starting with ```"ev_"``` where ```"_"``` value < char.MaxValue and we can have as many other characters after ```"_"``` as well?

So "evaz" < "evz", but "evza" > "evz" right? Or "evza" = "evz"?

Comment: @kuskmen Yes, that's correct, that "evza" is > "evz".  Equality is only if they are exactly the same.

Comment: Very well, thank you sir. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?